# Javascript canvas linear gradient not going to full color

Tags: javascript, canvas, gradient

I'm currently coding a color picker for a website I'm making and
the linear gradient doesn't seem to be going to full white.
I'm using a canvas to get the RGB color data.
See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tCSt.png)

As you can see, I get a maximum value of 254.
I use the following function to draw the gradient to the canvas.

```
draw_color_square(hue){
    var gradB = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 255);
    gradB.addColorStop(0, "white");
    gradB.addColorStop(1, "black");

    var gradC = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,255,0);
    gradC.addColorStop(0, "hsla(" + hue + ",100%,50%,0)");
    gradC.addColorStop(1, "hsla(" + hue + ",100%,50%,1)");

    this.ctx.fillStyle = gradB;
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 255, 255);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = gradC;
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 255, 255);
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}
```

I have checked that the slider goes to position [0, 0]

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle with a working example, please? Mention me when you have done so

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1ka8ejx/29/ (note that values other than RGB don't work yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost everything shifted by 1 pixel. The canvas must be 256 pixel width, and you have it set to 255 pixels. You fillrect only fills 255 pixels width, and your gradients start at pixel 0 (which don't exists as far as I can see) up to pixel 255. I've updated everything for it to work as expected.

The most important part was this one:

```
draw_color_square(hue){
    var gradB = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(1, 1, 1, 256);
    gradB.addColorStop(0, "white");
    gradB.addColorStop(1, "black");

    var gradC = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(1,1,256,1);
    gradC.addColorStop(0, "hsla(" + hue + ",100%,50%,0)");
    gradC.addColorStop(1, "hsla(" + hue + ",100%,50%,1)");

    this.ctx.fillStyle = gradB;
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = gradC;
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}
```

Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1ka8ejx/45/

Comment: @IBronchart Did the answer helped you? If so, please, check it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Why in the top right corner we get the value 255 1 1 instead of 255 0 0? And also does this work on custom dimensions? not 255x255?